# Is there a new stockpile hotkey?

Tags: dwarf-fortress-premium

In Dwarf Fortress Premium, is there a hotkey to create a new stockpile?  I can get to the Stockpile menu with <kbd>p</kbd>, but there is no hotkey displayed to create a new one.

[image: Screesnhot with new stockpile button circled]

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one yet, sadly....